# jQuery not loading data on a select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a main PHP page that uses jQuery to load the different pages for actions that the user can do.

[image: Main page]

This is where the user do everything. It has an jQuery script that when you click an orange element `<p>`.

When you click "Solicitar Software", jQuery loads "solicitudes.php". This php page has its own script.

[image]

When "solicitudes.php" page loads, its PHP script runs.

```
require('conexion.php');
$conexion = new connection();

$query = "SELECT * FROM Carreras";
$resultado = mysql_query($query, $conexion -> conn) or die('ERROR:' .$query);

?>
```

The script loads all the careers in the database and add add them to the `<select>` as you can see:

[image]

The problem is here, when I click on a carrer, it does not load the list subjects related to the career. But, if I access the PHP file alone, it works well.

[image]

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#carrera").change( //Select a carrer
        function()
        {
                var carreraId = $('#carrera option:selected').val();
                var queryMaterias = "carreraid=" + carreraId + "&valor=" + $("#valor").val();

                jQuery.ajax({
                  url: 'acciones.php',
                  type: 'GET',
                  dataType: 'text',
                  data: queryMaterias,
                  success: function(data) 
                  {
                    $("#lmateria").empty();
                    $("#lmateria").append(data); //Add subjects to the <select>
                    // $("#lmateria").html(data);
                  },
                  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //called when there is an error
                    alert(errorThrown);
                  }, 
                });

        }
);
});
```

Am I doing something wrong? What may be the problem? Thanks for the help.

Main page:

```
<html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Sistema de Administración</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//necolas.github.com/normalize.css/2.1.0/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/administrador.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/administrador.js"></script> 

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="acciones">
        <p id="logo">
            <img src="images/logo1.jpg" alt="logo">
        </p>
        <p id="division">Agregar Division</p>
        <p id="carrera">Agregar Carrera</p>
        <p id="materia">Agregar Materia</p>
        <p id="software">Agregar Software</p>
        <p id="profesor">Agregar Profesor</p>
        <p id="ssoftware">Solicitar Software</p>
        <p id="solicitudes">Lista de Solicitudes</p>
        <center><input type="button" id="logout" value="Salir" onclick="window.location.href='acciones.php?valor=5'"></center>
    </div>
    <div id="resultado">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

jQuery loads "solicitud.php" on the `<div> resultado`.

Solicitud.php:

```
<!doctype html>

<?php  

require('conexion.php');
$conexion = new connection();

$query = "SELECT * FROM Carreras";
$resultado = mysql_query($query, $conexion -> conn) or die('ERROR:' .$query);

?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/solicitud.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/solicitud.js"></script> 

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h2>Solicitud de Software</h2>
    </header>
    <form action="acciones.php" id="solicitud" method = "GET">
        <select name="carrera" id="carrera">
            <option value="">Seleccione una carrera</option>
            <?php 
                while ($datos = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) #MUESTRA LOS ROLES
                            { 
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $datos['id'];?>"><?php echo utf8_encode($datos['Carrera']);?></option>
            <?php 
                            }
            ?>
        </select>

        <select name="materias" id="lmateria">
            <option value="">Potato</option>
        </select>

        <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombre" name="nombre">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Codigo" id="codigo" name="codigo">
        <input type="button" value="Agregar" id="enviar"> -->
        <input type="hidden" id="valor" name="valor" value='17'>
    </form>
    <h3 id="exito">Agregado!</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have options in your response i.e data ??

Comment: data holds the response of the query. It is a string that contains the options:     $return .= "<option value='$value'>$text</option>";    print $return;   This is on the php file that does the query.

Comment: Not all browsers like having the innerHTML of `select` elements changed in that way. Try creating a new `select` element with the new options in jQuery, then loop to transfer the options across to the existing `select` element on the page.

Comment: try var carreraId = $('#carrera :selected').val();

Comment: I did that before with no results. It works if i use "solicitudes.php" page, but if i use "solicitudes.php" inside the main page, it does not load. I've tried with Fifox and Chrome with no luck.

Comment: Where is the jquery code placed? is it in the main php page or the solicitudes.php page?

Comment: @KaranPunamiya Main and "solicitudes" have their own jquery script. In Main, the jQuery scritp loads "solicitudes" inside the Main page. The "solicitudes" script, loads the list of subjects when you select a career using AJAX.

Comment: @exampleusername it keeps working the same way. I did that before and changed it but no change.

Comment: try using on function. `$("#carrera").on('change',function(){`

Comment: Use this function jQuery("#carrera").live('change',function(){ });

Comment: @BharatChodvadiya This is working. I can see on firebug the petition, now the problem is that it's not reading the selected value. But thanks for the help!

Comment: Do not use live , better use on as live is deprecated http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: No, don't use `.live()`. (a) Select elements' 'change' events don't bubble. (b) `.live()` is deprecated.

Comment: Just use this var carreraId = $('#carrera').val();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the HTML, I'm not sure this is 100% correct but should point you in the right direction :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#carrera").change(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'acciones.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                carreraid: $('#carrera').val(),//possibly?
                valor: $("#valor").val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                //In my experince, this is the safe way to replace (or append) options.
                $("#lmateria").find("option").each(function(i, opt) {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
                //Wrap in <select>...</select> only if not already included in data.
                $("<select>" + data + "</select>").find("option").each(function(i, opt) {
                    $("#lmateria").append(opt);
                });
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //called when there is an error
                alert(errorThrown);
            }, 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Just tested it. It works if i use "solicitudes.php" page alone, but if i use "solicitudes.php" inside the main page, it does not load. Using firebug, seems like not doing the petition when inside the main page.

Comment: aerojun, can you edit the question to show the overall structure of the document (HTML) please. Not the detail, just the main elements, particularly, the big blue rectangle and its initial contents.

Comment: Just found one BIG mistake. I had 2 elements named "carrera".

Answer (score 1):

This may be stupid...It was my mistake all along.

I had 2 elements named "carrera", so jQuery did not know what to do. Just changed it and it worked.

On Main, i had an element named "carrera" and on 'Solicitud.php' i had other one, thats why it worked on one page and not on the other one.

Thanks everybody!.

Comment: +1 for total honesty aerojun :) Good luck with the rest of the project.

Comment: Thanks!. I was looking for that mistake for about 12 hours D:

Comment: And you can congratulate yourself that it was *you* who found it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute url in ajax call. `url: '/path/to/acciones.php'`

Comment: Both files are on the same folder.